# python multiprocessing

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

```
import time
from random import randint
import os
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def gat(number):
    result = number * 2
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by: {2}'.format(number, result, proc_name), '№ процесса', os.getpid())
    time.sleep(5)
   
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tt = int("1",16)
    start = datetime.now()
    procs = []
    for number in range(tt , 1000000, 10):
     p_list = [Process(target=gat, args=(number,)) for _ in range(4)]
     for p in p_list:
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
     for p in p_list:
        p.join()
```

вывод резулбтата:

```
 1 doubled to 2 by: Process-1 № процесса 34156
    1 doubled to 2 by: Process-3 № процесса 6860
    1 doubled to 2 by: Process-2 № процесса 21248
    1 doubled to 2 by: Process-4 № процесса 43948
    11 doubled to 22 by: Process-5 № процесса 21740
    11 doubled to 22 by: Process-6 № процесса 38564
    11 doubled to 22 by: Process-7 № процесса 2516
    11 doubled to 22 by: Process-8 № процесса 34140
    21 doubled to 42 by: Process-9 № процесса 39400
    21 doubled to 42 by: Process-10 № процесса 28212
    21 doubled to 42 by: Process-11 № процесса 14160
    21 doubled to 42 by: Process-12 № процесса 25208
```

собственно вопрос:
как сделать, что бы процессам отдавалось свое число(параметр).

в моем случае, в каждой итерации всем процессам отдается одно и тоже число

как сделать чтоб первый процесс брал первое число из диапазона `for number in range(tt , 1000000, 10)` , второй процесс 2-е число, третий - 3-е, четвертый - 4-е.

у меня 4-ре процесса и хочу чтобы они по порядку разбирали диапазон

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from random import randint
import os
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def gat(number):
    result = number * 2
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by: {2}'.format(number, result, proc_name), '№ процесса', os.getpid())
    time.sleep(5)
   
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tt = int("1",16)
    start = datetime.now()
    procs = []
    for number in range(tt , 1000000, 4):
     p_list = [Process(target=gat, args=(number,)) for number in range(number , 1000000, 1)[:4]]
     for p in p_list:
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
     for p in p_list:
        p.join()
```

вывод

```
1 doubled to 2 by: Process-1 № процесса 17924
2 doubled to 4 by: Process-2 № процесса 37368
3 doubled to 6 by: Process-3 № процесса 36392
4 doubled to 8 by: Process-4 № процесса 28068
5 doubled to 10 by: Process-5 № процесса 12304
6 doubled to 12 by: Process-6 № процесса 45960
7 doubled to 14 by: Process-7 № процесса 45576
8 doubled to 16 by: Process-8 № процесса 33068
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно догадываюсь, вам надо что-то такое:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    lst = pool.map(gat, (x for x in range(tt , 1000000)))
    # lst - готовый результат. Но поскольку вы ничего не возвращаете, 
    #       это будет список из None
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь
вариант с pool попробую чуть позже